# Setting up home using Home kit framework in iOS8

Tags: ios, homekit

I would like to create `HMHome` with `HMHomeManager` and `addHomeWithName`.

```
HMHomeManager * myHomeManager;

[myHomeManager addHomeWithName:@"My Home" completionHandler:^(HMHome *home, NSError *error) 
{

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Created Home : %@",home.name);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Error : %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

When the application is run I am getting the following error instead of creating Home

```
Error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error -70892.).
```

Comment: FYI you can find errors labels in HMErrorDomain class. Yours is : HMErrorUnconfiguredParameter (-70892). Not sure what it means ... Your code doesn't show the `alloc]init]` on `myHomeManager`...

Comment: HMHomeManager * myHomeManager = [HMHomeManager alloc]init]; even though I have included this in my application I am getting the error.

Comment: Its recommended if you @user3400046 agreed with the below answer accept that one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your class the HMHomeManager delegate:

```
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class HomeManagerViewController: UITableViewController, HMHomeManagerDelegate {

    var homeViewController: HomeViewController? = nil
    var myHomeManager:HMHomeManager? = nil

    var homes = [AnyObject]()   // datasource for tableview
```

Your HMHomeManager has to be initialised first ( you've mentioned that you've already done this), and your class set to be its delegate.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myHomeManager = HMHomeManager()
    myHomeManager!.delegate = self
```

You Add the Home in whatever function you want (i.e. when user taps the "+" button to insert a new home into a tableview list)

The HMHomeManager must have time to connect to the homekit database

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject)
{
    myHomeManager!.addHomeWithName( uniqueHomeName , completionHandler: { (home: HMHome!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            // adding the home failed; check error for why
            NSLog("Error : %@",[error.localizedDescription])
        }
        else
        {
            // success!

            // Insert home at bottom of datasource array and bottom of tableview cells
            self.homes.append(home)

            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.homes.count-1, inSection: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
    })
}
```

You then update your tableviews datasource in the homeManagerDidUpdateHomes delegate method.

This function is called when HMHomeManager finished initialising and will give you an array of any previously added homes

```
    // #pragma mark - HMHomeManager Delegate

func homeManagerDidUpdateHomes(manager: HMHomeManager!) {

    self.homes = manager!.homes

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When the app is first run there should be a request to access its "**Accessory Data**".

Make sure you tap "OK" for this.

[image: Accessory Data]

Also: Add "HomeKit" under your apps entitlements:

1. Choose your app **Target**.
2. Select the "**Capabilities**" tab.
3. Switch "**HomeKit**" to "On".
4. Enter your developer Id, etc.

example image attached

[image: Adding HomeKit Entitlements]

Comment: HomeKit in Capabilities tab is set to "ON". Even though I am getting the Error instead of creating home.

Comment: Added the Insertion function. The HMHomeManager must finish initialising before you try to use it to add a new home. When homeManagerDidUpdateHomes is called then you know initialisation is complete

Comment: If this is the correct answer then it would help others if it was marked as correct by you

Comment: That would be a new question. Mark this current question as correct (as it answers your original question) and start a new question regarding the addAccessory problem.