# HomeKit throws Error 77 & 78

Tags: ios, icloud, ios8, homekit

Every time I make a call to HomeKit on my iPod Touch 5th gen, I consistently get this error:

```
Printing description of error:

Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=78 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error 78.)"
```

This is on a call to `homeManager.addHomeWithName()`. I think that code 78 is
`CloudDataSyncInProgress`

This has been happening for days, though. What can I do to fix it?

If I sign out of iCloud and try again, I get code 77 (`KeychainSyncNotEnabled`).

Comment: I had forgotten I had signed out iCloud Keychain (iOS Settings > iCloud > Keychain) and was getting `HMErrorDomain Code=78` as well.  I went back in and enabled iCloud Keychain and had to enter a password and then verification code.  From your description I'm guessing reenabling iCloud Keychain did not help?

Comment: Well that's strange.

The 78 code in my seed means :

    HMErrorCodeKeychainSyncNotEnabled                  = 78,

Comment: Any resolution to this?  Similar issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607567/setting-up-home-using-home-kit-framework-in-ios8/24695997#24695997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference for the error codes are provided in NSError+HomeKit.m in the HMCatalog sample project for HomeKit.  (See "https://developer.apple.com/homekit/")  Note that you do not need to be a developer to access these resources.

The relevant error code pairs from the dictionary provided in that file are:

(int)76 : @"Keychain Sync Not Enabled"
(int)77 : @"Cloud Data Sync In Progress"
(int)78 : @"Network Unavailable"

At first glance, I would think this indicates a poor WiFi connection?

To clean up the iCloud Keychain for HomeKit, I found the following process worked.

- note: when you follow this process, all home information needs to be rebuilt

1) navigate to Settings > iCloud > Keychain
   disable the iCloud Keychain setting.

2) navigate to Settings > Privacy > HomeKit
   select the "Reset HomeKit Configuration..."

3) navigate to Settings > iCloud > Keychain
   enable iCloud Keychain setting

Comment: I can't find where to reset HomeKit configuration in iOS 10. Can you please update for iOS 10?

Answer (score 1):

I am using iOS 9 beta and I had the same error 77 "Cloud Data Sync In Progress" and tried steps 1,2,3 over and over again and couldn't get it to work.

To finally get the app to work I did the following

1. Removed the app.
2. Turned off keychain. *(Settings > iCloud > Keychain disable the iCloud Keychain setting)*
3. Signed out of iCloud. *(Settings > iCloud -> Sign Out)*
4. Reset Homekit *(Settings > Privacy > HomeKit select the "Reset HomeKit Configuration")*
5. Signed in to iCloud. *(Settings > iCloud -> Sign In)*
6. Turned on keychain through security code. *(Settings > iCloud > Keychain enable iCloud Keychain setting)*
7. Installed app.
8. Gave app permission to HomeKit home data.